# Dynamically change a styled background color; XAML/VB in Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows 8

Tags: vb.net, xaml, visual-studio-2012

In a DataTemplate in StandardStyles.xaml I have this StackPanel:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="Standard160x160ItemTemplate">
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="160" Height="160">
        ...
        <StackPanel 
            VerticalAlignment="Top" 
            Background="{StaticResource ListViewItemOverlayBackgroundThemeBrush}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding UniqueID}" 
                       Foreground="{StaticResource ListViewItemOverlayForegroundThemeBrush}" 
                       Style="{StaticResource TitleTextStyle}" Height="30" Margin="15,0,15,0"/>
        </StackPanel>
        ...
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

"uniqueID" is a property of a "Product" class:

```
Public NotInheritable Class Product
    Private Property _sUID As String = String.Empty
    Public Property UniqueID As String
        Get
            Return Me._sUID
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            Me.SetProperty(Me._sUID, value)
        End Set
    End Property
    ...
End Class
```

I use above template "Standard160x160ItemTemplate" in a grid view item like this:

```
                   <GridView Height="210" 
                        x:Name="ItemView"
                        SelectionMode="None"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource itemsViewSource}}">
                        <GridViewItem
                            x:Name="GridViewItem"
                            ContentTemplate="{StaticResource Standard160x160ItemTemplate}" 
                            Tapped="GridViewItem_Tapped">
                            <GridViewItem.Style>
                                <Style TargetType="FrameworkElement">
                                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,0"/>
                                </Style>
                            </GridViewItem.Style>
                        </GridViewItem>
                    </GridView>
```

This works well and does what it should.

However, in some cases (depending on two other properties of the "Product" object, specifically if one of them has a lower UInt value than the other) I want to change the StackPanel's background to a solid "Red" instead of "{StaticResource ListViewItemOverlayBackgroundThemeBrush}".

I don't doubt it is possible, but I am new to XAML (not to VB though) and am still overwhelmed by the thousands of XAML tags and am really struggling to find a solution.

So the question is: How can I dynamically change the template's background, based on the "Product" properties "A" and "B"?

Answer (score 1):

The best way would probably be to use custom IValueConverter. [Here's the example from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.data.ivalueconverter.aspx).